# How to add a text representing categorical data in matplotlib and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a code that generates a gantt chart and I would like to add categorical value (filter value) as a text/annotation to the plot (possibly as a title).

I have two dataframes which are used to plot the gantt chart below. One dataframe represents scheduled times for the operations and the other one represents actual times. Initially, both dataframes contain data for many work centers but I filter them so it would only display data for one work center by using this command: `df = df.loc[df1['Work center'] == '503AL302']`.

In my code, I filter both dataframes by the same `work center` and I would like to show that the data only captures data for a certain work center. In this particular case it is '503AL302'. I don't want to manually input the work center as a string in a title but want to display the value used to filter the `work centers`. In the future, I will be changing the filters based on the value of the `work center` and I want the graph to automatically display which work center's data is represented. The main goal of this is to clearly see which work center is selected, it doesn't necessarily be a title or legend.

Here is my code that generates a gantt chart. Let me know and I can provide sample data along with it for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
df = pd.read_csv('zpp00141_new.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('sample_data1.csv')
df = df.loc[df['Work Center'] == '503AL302']
df1 = df1.loc[df1['Work center'] == '503AL302']
#convert times to number to calculate
def timestr_to_num(timestr):
    return mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime('0' + timestr if timestr[1] == ':' else timestr, '%I:%M:%S %p'))
#gantt chart plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.5, 6))
operations = pd.unique(df['Operation/Activity'])
#Declaring a colormap
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma_r')
colors = [cmap(i/20) for i in range(20)]
#plot scheduled operations 
for operation, color in zip(operations, colors):
    for row in df[df['Operation/Activity'] == operation].itertuples():
        left = timestr_to_num(row.start)
        right = timestr_to_num(row.finish)
        ax.barh(operation, left=left, width=right - left, height=1, color="#6ED06F", edgecolor = 'black', label = operation)
#plot "Actual" operations' times     
operations1 = pd.unique(df1['Operation/Activity'])
for operation, color in zip(operations1, colors):
    for row in df1[df1['Operation/Activity'] == operation].itertuples():
        left = timestr_to_num(row.start)
        right = timestr_to_num(row.finish)
        ax.barh(operation, left=left, width=right - left, height=0.4, color='#33AFFF', edgecolor = 'black', label = operation)
        #plt.legend()
#set x-axis limit
ax.set_xlim(timestr_to_num('06:00:00 AM'), timestr_to_num('4:30:00 PM'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))  # display ticks as hours and minutes
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))  # set a tick every hour
#set y and x labels
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize = 'large')
ax.set_ylabel('Operation', fontsize = 'large')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.set_yticklabels(list(df['Operation/Activity'] + " - " + df['Operation short text'].astype(str)))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=11)
#add a title to a plot
plt.title("Schedule", fontsize = 'x-large')
#convert "now" time to a certain format of hours:minutes:seconds am/pm and plot a vertical red line for the "Current time"
now = datetime.now()
now = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
plt.axvline(x=timestr_to_num(now),color='r', animated = True)
#adding the legend
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#33AFFF', label='Actual')
patch2 = mpatches.Patch(color='#6ED06F', label='Planned')
plt.legend(handles=[patch, patch2], loc='upper left', fontsize = 'large')
plt.show()
```

Sample data for zpp00141(planned schedule):

```
Operation short text,Operation/Activity,Earl. start / time,Latest finish / time,Work Center
Mount right racks,0250,7:00:00 AM,9:22:00 AM,503AL302
Mount right side motion unit carriage,0251,9:22:00 AM,10:30:00 AM,503AL302
Mount left side motion unit carriage,0252,10:30:00 AM,11:17:00 AM,503AL302
Install motion unit complete,0253,11:17:00 AM,1:01:00 PM,503AL302
Move machine to next step + EPA,0254,1:01:00 PM,3:30:00 PM,503AL302
Mount Left Racks,0200,7:00:00 AM,9:12:00 AM,503AL302
Mount cable motor & Lubricate guide carr,0201,9:12:00 AM,9:44:00 AM,503AL302
Mount suction components,0202,9:44:00 AM,11:04:00 AM,503AL302
Mount extraction,0203,11:04:00 AM,12:34:00 PM,503AL302
Mount temporary diamond plates,0204,12:34:00 PM,1:04:00 PM,503AL302
Mount piping inside,0205,1:04:00 PM,1:44:00 PM,503AL302
Move Machine to next step + EPA,0206,1:44:00 PM,3:30:00 PM,503AL302
```

Sample data for zpp00138(actual times):

```
Work center,Operation/Activity,Operation short text,Actual finish (time),Actual start (time)
503AL302,0201,Mount cable motor & Lubricate guide carr,10:22:26 AM,9:32:41 AM
503AL302,0202,Mount suction components,2:21:41 PM,10:23:03 AM
503AL302,0203,Mount extraction,2:22:58 PM,2:22:26 PM
503AL302,0204,Mount temporary diamond plates,2:24:28 PM,2:24:00 PM
503AL302,0250,Mount right racks,9:34:26 AM,6:02:45 AM
503AL302,0251,Mount right side motion unit carriage,10:50:17 AM,9:35:47 AM
503AL302,0253,Install motion unit complete,2:02:47 PM,12:28:33 PM
503AL302,0254,Move machine to next step + EPA,2:14:35 PM,2:02:58 PM
503AL302,0200,Mount Left Racks,9:30:59 AM,7:02:30 AM
503AL302,0205,Mount piping inside,2:25:23 PM,2:24:51 PM
503AL302,0206,Move Machine to next step + EPA,4:12:31 PM,2:26:39 PM
503AL302,0252,Mount left side motion unit carriage,12:28:22 PM,10:51:01 AM
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful, yes.

Comment: @BigBen I edited the post and provided sample data. Thank you for looking into this!